# Python memoization decorator

Tags: python, wiki, memoization

I was looking for an example of a memoization decorator in Python2.

So far I found this one (in official? wiki): https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize

My question is: does anybody see a bug in this code?

Line #13: `if not isinstance(args, collections.Hashable)`
will always return `True`, since `args` will always be a hashable tuple.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that appears to be an error in the code.

It appears to have been introduced in [this edit](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary?action=diff&rev1=115&rev2=116).